# Reference for Bessel's interpolation formula

Tags: reference-request, interpolation

Please give me a reference for a standard, easy-to-find, textbook where I can find the full proof of Bessel's interpolation formula?

Thank you.

Comment: pretty much any textbook on numerical methods can help you out, and there is a variety of online courses: http://nptel.ac.in/courses/111107062/22  --- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m0nE5izQI6k

Answer (score 1):

A very good reference: Demidovich, Maron. Computational mathematics. (Translated from Russian). 1981.

Chapter 14 The Interpolation of functions (Very clear written). $$ 14.10 Bessel's interpolation formula.